# Android - How to retrieve BLOB image from sqlite and display in app

Tags: android, sqlite

Uploading the image:

1. I click my empty imageView and it will bring up the android emulator gallery
2. From there i choose a photo and then click on upload button
3. It is successful and will be saved in sqlite as a BLOB

Question is what are the neccessary codes for me to retrieve the image and display on my app?

upload onClick:

```
        Student student = new Student(profadmin.getText().toString());
        student.setImageUri(ImageUri);
        stud.updateImage(student);
        Toast passes = Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Profile Picture has been updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        passes.show();
```

My database Handler:

```
public int updateImage(Student student) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(STUDENT_IMAGEURI, student.getImageUri().toString());


    int rowsAffected = db.update(STUDENT_TABLE, values, STUDENT_ADMINNO + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(student.getAdminNo())});
    db.close();

    return rowsAffected;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be smarter to save the image into a file system, like create a a directory for each user, and store the image in that. Then you can save the file's path to the database, and then use the file's path ti display said image?